# Mouse in rectangle scaling issue in Game Maker

Tags: user-interface, mouse, game-maker

I am working on a game with GUI elements in Game Maker, and have run into an issue. 
I have a button on the background and if you hover over it, it shows a blue GUI rectangle on top. This is the code that I use for it:

```
if point_in_rectangle(window_mouse_get_x(),window_mouse_get_y(),32,672,160,736) 
{
    draw_set_alpha(0.3);
    if (mouse_check_button_pressed(mb_left))
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
else { draw_set_alpha(0); }

draw_set_color(global.colLBlue);
draw_rectangle(32,672,160,736,false);
```

The problem now is that the rectangle that I check for, and the rectangle that is drawn don't match up. I have tried to solve it by making a view, but the way I did it now doesn't work. Does anyone know how I can make the 'check' rectangle coordinates match up with the GUI? (I have already set the GUI to scale with the window, so that stays in the right place)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve mouse coordinates relative to GUI, you should use `device_mouse_x_to_gui` \ `device_mouse_y_to_gui`. Index 0 is the mouse on desktop platforms.